# Processing hugely varied JSON data from Facebook Graph API news feed

Tags: json, facebook, facebook-graph-api, formatting, feed

OK so I have authenticated fine and understand JSON including how to process it with PHP...

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

But my issues are that the JSON data that the API returns after hitting up FB...me/home end point is very varied.  I understand that so is the data on a FB news stream but...

My end game is to show this info in a mash-up with other data but there seems no clear way of formatting it and each item in the JSON response is hugely different with different values.  No consistent "item_type" : "photo / status update / message" that I could use to template it up into nicely formatted content blocks on the front end?

Any suggestions on the best way to process / style this type of vary varied JSON?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking out Google's gson library for parsing through JSON documents. Assuming that you are familiar with Java it makes it relatively easy to develop a custom parser that can adapt to documents stored under a flexible schema.

The library page is [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/). You can find the JsonReader documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html).

Edit: It also might help to post some example documents so we can get a better idea of what kinds of results you're getting.

Comment: thanks for your input.  I am trying to add this to a web based app that is already half done in PHP.  The JSON lib you suggest seems good but I would prefer to stay away from Java and keep it all on one code base.  I know I can use (PHP) json_decode($json) but its the lack of consistency or common values in the FB JSON making it hard to dispay / process - thanks anyway